# Passing Subclasses for instantiation

Tags: java

I have an abstract class `Tool`, it is subclassed by various Classes like `Hammer`, `Screwdriver`, etc.

`Tool` has a Constructor with parameters

```
Tool(String name, double weight, double length)
```

I would then like to within another Class, `ToolUser`, create objects from a `Tool` Class that is passed to it.

```
class ToolUser {
    void createTool(***pass the Tool somehow here***) {
        for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {         
           // create Tool object from passed Tool Class 
           // could be Hammer, Screwdriver, etc. whatever was passed
        }

        // ToolUser will then use the instantiated objects as 
        // Tool objects.. it doesn't care if they are Hammers, 
        // Screwdrivers or anything else.. it will just access them as
        // a Tool object
    }
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to do this passing `Hammer` to `createTool(Class toolClass)`, the reason was because the java compiler complained about using subclasses..

is this possible somehow using Reflection or Lambda expressions?

I also would like to pass along the parameter data somehow (weight and length) so that I can either instantiate the Class using those parameters - if that is possible.

Anyone have any ideas how to do this.. I know nothing about lambda expressions really and my attempts at using Reflection have failed.

Comment: It would have helped if you included the compiler error you are getting.

Comment: What did the compiler complain about exactly?

Comment: ah, i can't remember the exact error message.. that will take some time as I need to recreate the code.. I had deleted the code that wasn't working.

Comment: I suggest looking more into the idea of a _Factory Pattern_.  It is what I would use to approach this problem.

Comment: Why are you instantiating the object? It seems like all the details for how to instantiate it are coming from the outside?

Comment: Do all your `Tool` subclasses have the same constructor parameter list?

Comment: yes, they have the same constructor signature.. I am passing these classes from the outside because I want to dynamically create a variable amount at runtime.. you can think of it kind of like a library. The code I'm writing now will be completed, then can be used like a library to write other projects... these projects will specify which subclass and parameters exactly to pass to the library. The library will then work with what it was passed, instantiating a variable number of these subclass Tool objects (all of the same class that was passed).

Comment: The tools will be of the same type, will they also be initialized with the same constructor parameter values?

Comment: no, values will be different.. like I said, think of it like calling a library. But, I guess parameters in constructors just overly complicate things. This can be worked around just by setting fields instead of parameters and having a parameterless constructor. So for this question, we can forget about parameters - to simplify things.. I was just thinking maybe using lambda expressions instead of reflection there was a way to also pass parameters with different values - but it's not that important for the code.

Comment: There are tons of ways to solve this, indeed. I'd like you to edit your question and describe exactly what the client will be passing in and what they'll be getting out.

Comment: nothing comes out, the class is just passed in for processing (to instantiate a variable number of objects from that class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from the question, you need to create an instance in the method based on the type, one way to achieve this is Reflection

```
 void createTool(Class<? extends Tool> clazz) { // allow Tool and its subtypes
  // subtypes should have constructors matching this signature  
  Tool tool = clazz.getConstructor(String.class,double.class,double.class)
                   .newInstance("name", weight,length);
  // deal with exceptions...
 }
```

and you can call it like this

```
   createTool(Hammer.class);
   createTool(Screwdriver.class);
```

Comment: I don't know, you should know more than me about how your program works

Comment: Will every `Tool` subtype have the same constructor signature?

Comment: They must invoke a super constructor, but their signatures can be different.

Comment: I will play with this, quite possibly it is what I need.. as I was not using this ? operator when I first tried it before I wrote the question on Stack Exchange

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a `ToolFactory` class to create specific `Tool` subclasses based on parameters.

So `ToolUser` would use a `ToolFactory`

e.g.

```
class ToolFactory
{
    // create a screwdriver
    static Tool createScrewdriver();
    // create a hammer
    static Tool createHammer();
    // figure out what sort of tool the user wants and create it
    static Tool createSomeTool(int width, int height, int weight);
}
```

Another approach would be a factory interface:

```
interface ToolFactory
{
    Tool createTool(int length, int weight);
}


class ToolUser 
{
    void createTool(ToolFactory factory) 
    {
        for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {         
           Tool t = factory.createTool(i, i*2);
```

and pass that into the method anonymously:

```
createTool(new ToolFactory {
               Tool createTool(int length, int weight) {
                   return new Screwdriver(int length, int weight);
               }
           });
```

Comment: I think you meant for that class to be `abstarct`? As well, I don't think the class should be abstract at all.. Those methods should be pre-defined, and return an instance of a `Tool` subclass. E.g. `Tool t = ToolFactory.createHammer();`

Comment: Why would it be abstract? Sure, I'm not showing the whole implementation, but then it is just a sample to show the API. Have a look at the factory pattern?

Comment: Downvoters please explain. If I've missed the point I'll delete my answer, else why is it bad?

Comment: I think the goal is to pass in information about what to instantiate and how to instantiate it. The `ToolFactory` is the _how_. You haven't provided the _what_.